# Django Website Http Error 405; Method Not Allowed (POST): /dashboard/

Tags: django, authentication, http-status-code-405

I am trying to access my 'dashboard' page after signing in on the 'login' page in Django. The url in  is throwing http error 405. If I replace the url with another page (eg: 'dbtable') it works absolutely fine. Below is my code in django:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.register_login, name='login'),
    path('dashboard/', DashboardPageView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
        path('dbtable/', views.DBTableView, name = 'dbtable'),
]
```

views.py (includes login view and dashboard view):

```
def register_login(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if "register" in request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST) == "Register"
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = form.cleaned_data['username']
            messages.success(request,"Account was Created for " + user)
        
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'login.html',context)
    
    if "login" in request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST['submit'] == 'Login':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Wrong Username or password')
    context = {}
    return render(request,'login.html',context)
            
class DashboardPageView(TemplateView): 
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(DashboardPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        
        context['plot'] = plot1.cumulative_plot()
        return context
```

login.html:

```
<!-- SIGN IN -->
            <div class="col align-items-center flex-col sign-in">
                <div class="form-wrapper align-items-center">
                    <div class="form sign-in">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <form  action = "{% url 'dashboard' %}" method="POST" name="login" value="login">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
                                <input type="text" name = "username"  placeholder="Username" class="form-control" Required>
                        
                            <i class='bx bxs-lock-alt'></i>
                            <input type="password" name = "password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" Required>
                                <button type="submit" >
                                    Sign in
                                </button>
                                <p>
                                    <b>
                                        Forgot password?
                                    </b>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <span>
                                        Don't have an account?
                                    </span>
                                    <b onclick="toggle()" class="pointer">
                                        Sign up here
                                    </b>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

This is what appears on the terminal:

> [02/Oct/2022 17:04:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4720

> Method Not Allowed (POST): /dashboard/

> Method Not Allowed: /dashboard/

> [02/Oct/2022 17:04:42] "POST /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: For anyone arriving here after migrating to Django 5.0 and facing a `405 Method Not Allowed` error, please note that as of this version, the `LogoutView` (from `django.contrib.auth.views`) no longer accepts `GET` requests (`POST` only). See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#features-removed-in-5-0) for more details and [here](https://codereviewdoctor.medium.com/3-awesome-django-4-1-changes-1-is-a-logout-deprecation-you-need-to-know-about-1d8166ccbdb2) for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your sign in form is submitting the form to the dashboard view. The dashboard view only defines a get method which is why you get the error. But anyway, I suppose you intended to submit this form to the `register_login` view.

**Change:**

```html
<form  action = "{% url 'dashboard' %}" method="POST" name="login" value="login">
```

**To:**

```html
<form  action = "{% url 'login' %}" method="POST" name="login" value="login">
```

Also, probably after redirecting from the login view on success, you want to redirect to the dashboard, not the login page again.

```py
# ... the rest of the code
if "login" in request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST['submit'] == 'Login':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:  # This is the success part
            login(request,user)
            # Instead of login, redirect to dashboard if the credentials
            # are correct.
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Wrong Username or password')
# ... the rest of the code
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although, when I change the url to "login" and I click the sign in button, it stays on the same page.

Comment: <div class="col align-items-center flex-col sign-in">
    <div class="form-wrapper align-items-center">
     <div class="form sign-in">
      <div class="input-group">
       <form  action = "{% url 'login' %}" method="POST" name="login" value="login">
                 {% csrf_token %}

Comment: Is there a way I could convert the get method to post on dashboard view? I am pretty new to Django and I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: It stays on the same page because you need to redirect to dashboard after successful login. I'll add more details to the answer. There is no need to support post in the dashboard view as far as I understand because the dashboard does not have any forms.

Comment: The redirect is not working for some reason, I did change the return redirect part and <form action = ""> part but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Ill try to figure something out. Thank you anyways! :)

Comment: You can add a `post` method in the dashboard view by implementing it in the class, but I don't think this is what you need.